# What is the best way to get the Median of a Data Frame

Tags: python, dataframe, row, addition

I have a Python Data Frame with Columns: Type and Value. I need the median of all time, cache-misses, tx-start, ..., context-switches

in the end there should be one data frame which holds the median of this five blocks
[how realize this][1] in python?

All Data Types are Object, how to get time as float and the rest as integer?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/blr9D.png

Answer (score 0):

Based on how your data is structure you should transpose your data so that it's grouped by the columns of interest e.g. time / cache-missed etc. in your case.

Then once you have the data structured you can add column  to add the median right next to it. Or you could do this as a separate summarized dataframe.

Supporting material on transpose:

- https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-transpose.php

How to do median on a DF

- http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/median-function-python-pandas-dataframe-row-column-wise-median/